# What DC motor controller will work for a small toy train?

Tags: voltage, battery-operated, motor-controller, low-voltage

I'm thinking about modifying a battery-powered toy train to use a higher voltage battery so the toy can go faster. Like this:
https://youtu.be/qK-IVIllOBY?t=30

The 9V battery has a nice form factor for this application. Easier than putting 2-4 AAAs or AAs in there. But putting a 9V there is damaging for a motor/gearing setup designed for 1.5V (stock battery is a single C cell). To improve this, I'm wondering if it's practical to add a knob-style controller so that the voltage can be varied from 1.5V to 9V (or maybe 6V max). If it is indeed practical, I have a couple questions:

1. What is a good, small prebuilt controller that will work for these voltages? Something like [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIADUK5UC5327&cm_re=fan_speed_controllers-_-35-118-217-_-Product) but smaller and made to work for 1.5V to 9V instead of 6V-12V.
2. What will current draw be when running the toy at 1.5V compared to using a stock 1.5V battery? From what I can read at Wikipedia, a C cell has far more capacity than a 9V (8000mAH vs 550mAH), so I would expect battery life to be drastically reduced.

If there's a better way to accomplish my goal, I'm happy to hear about it!

Comment: a 9V battery will not last very long

Comment: The linked controller seems to be for a brushless DC CPU fan...probably not suitable. Try 2 or 3 1.5 volt cells in series to see what works.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking about a lipo or lifepo4 battery now since adding a controller seems like a lot of work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference in current draw with a 1.5V supply vs the 1.5V battery will be due to the difference in output resistance of each. Which is higher will depend on how the supply is designed.

However, since you want to drive this train faster without burning out the motor, you really want to use a current limiting supply.

If you can measure the typical stall current of the motor at 1.5V and build a driver that limits the current to under that value while being able to drive up to 9V, you should get the thing spinning around quite nicely with minimal over-heating. The brushes will wear faster though.

However, since you are looking for a prebuilt solution, this does not really help you, and unfortunately, we can not suggest devices here.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The problem is I don't know enough EE to really know what "current limiting supply" means. Or more specifically, whether some device I look at will work. I've read briefly about TRIAC and 555 circuits, Arduino motor speed controllers, and a slew of other things, but yeah, almost all of it has been at the schematic/DIY level instead of the prebuilt device level. Can you suggest the kind of device I need in somewhat layman terms? And if you don't know of any prebuilt device that works for these voltages, that would help to know too. :)

Comment: Would the fan controller I linked to above work even though the voltages I'm looking for are outside its rating?

Comment: @MattChambers an off the shelf one may work, but it's asking a bit much for folks on here to do that research for you, hence it is frowned upon. The one you linked is not really suitable.

Comment: @MattChambers there is a trick you can play if you do not need to have the voltage adjustable. Add a 9V flashlight bulb in series with the motor. The bulb will limit the current while the motor ramps up.